# Excel VBA - Sorting With Protected Row and Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm an average/intermediate VBA developer, mostly able to modify existing code and re-use code for expanding Excel projects.

We ran into a situation where someone recorded some Macro's in Excel 2013 but they won't work in Excel 2003. They HAVE to work in Excel 2003 due to the legacy nature of the machine this sheet will be primary on.

So, I did some research and re-wrote the code for the Macros so it would on 2003. However, of the 4 worksheets in this workbook, it only worked on the first page. It drove me crazy trying to figure out why. Finally noticed that on the other 3 worksheets, the first column and row are PROTECTED. If I unprotect them, the re-written Macros work.

So need a little advice on how to make these re-written macros work with the first row and column protected.

This is a sample of the Macro (there are multiple ones like this with just range differences):

```
Sub KA24()

' Had to Convert Macro to work with the older version of Excel 2003 in the 
 shop - BW - 8/31/2017

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("24 GA KY")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Ws.Range("D2:J9").Sort Key1:=Ws.Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
Header:=xlNo, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, 
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unprotect the Worksheet for use in your VBA code using the `UserInterFaceOnly` method. This assumes your sheet is password protected with the password "Something", if not just leave out the password part.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("24 GA KY")
Ws.Protect Password:="Something", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
...
```

Comment: I believe this may have done it. Testing more in the morning and will report back. Thank you SO much. :)

Comment: This did the track. Again, appreciate it.